# trigonometry equation, minus problem, $\sin{x}+\sin{5x}=0$

Tags: trigonometry

I solved this equation:
$$\sin{x}+\sin{5x}=0$$

in the book , there are 2 solutions: x=60k , x=45+90k. 
in my solution, I got the first solution right, but the second solution with a minus. 
I don't understand what I did wrong. please help :)

$$    \sin(x)+\sin(5x)=0 \\
    \sin(x) = -\sin(5x)
    \sin(x) = \sin(-5x) $$

$$    x = -5x + 360k \\
    6x = 360k \\
    x = 60k $$

$$    x = 180-(-5x)+360k \\
    x = 180+5x+360k \\
    -4x=180+360k \\
    x = -45 - 90k $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All numbers of the form $45+90k$ for integer $k$ are also numbers of the form $-45-90m$ for integer $m$:
$$ 45+90k = -45-90m \\
\iff 90(k+1)=90(-m)\\
\iff m=-k-1, $$
so your solution gives the same values as the book.